# Allowing <script> tag for some of the trusted sources while sanitization.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sanitization

I'm working on a CMS application, where users can build and manage their own websites. There is a CRUD of HTML pages, in which while creation/updation, we are sanitizing user's input and removing any JavaScript code.

Some user's need to add widgets on their pages, which can be from any source. How can I allow them to do so without compromising the security of their page ? Basically, I want to allow `<script>` tag from trusted sources and which might have some JavaScript content within them.

Comment: What issue specifically are you having?

Comment: @ruby_newbie If I allow `<script>` tag, then site will be vulnerable to XSS attack, but I want to allow `<script>` tags having trusted sources, so that users can add their widgets.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want JS on these pages, then you probably should not open Pandora's box by allowing some 'under certain circumstances'.

A 'trusted' source is hard enough to define and potentially even harder to control. Also, the original source may include 3rd party scripts and it would be near impossible to test and monitor every single one of them.

At the very least, I would recommend to embed widgets in iframes so that they can't interfere with the main page.

As a side note: you're probably already aware of that, but removing all JS code is not an easy task either as it may be included in many different places, be obfuscated, etc.

Just as a quick (and safe) example:

```html
<img src="foo" onerror="console.log(atob('SSBoYXMgaGFja2VkIHRoZSBJbnRlcm5ldHMhIQ=='))">
```

That said, I doubt that a user would intentionally corrupt his own page. Which raises another question: *do you really need to block JS in the first place?*

You may have specific reasons that are not obvious in your post, though.

All of this is based on my own understanding of your problem, so don't hesitate to provide us with more details if I missed the plot.